# Querying local SPARQL endpoint is very slow

Tags: python, sparql, virtuoso, rdflib

I have setup a local SPARQL endpoint with DBPedia database using Openlink Virtuoso through this [guide](https://medium.com/@nadjetba/how-to-setup-dbpedia-and-geonames-on-openlink-virtuoso-f203321fd0fe). Then I tried to query my database through Python with the help of RDFLib and SPARQLWrapper.

Problem is the time it take for a query (through Python) is very long, usually 2 to 3 seconds before I can get a result back. But when I use my browser to query directly at the endpoint (go to localhost from Chrome), for the same type of query I get the result instantly.

I don't think it's a problem with my Python code, because if I keep the same code and just change to DBPedia endpoint, I can get a query result within 0.1 to 0.2 seconds. My database file is around 6GB and I have configured the ini file to use more memory as instructed.

Anyone can troubleshoot the problem for me? I'm thinking I need to tweak some parameter with the virtuoso server but I don't know where to start. Thanks!

Here's what my query looks like (DBPedia endpoint or local endpoint directly from Chrome: almost instant result; local endpoint through Python: 2+ seconds):

```
sparql = SPARQLWrapper('http://localhost:8890/sparql')
sparql.setQuery('''
    SELECT ?id
    WHERE { 
     ?linkto dbo:wikiPageID ?id.
     ?origin    dbo:wikiPageWikiLink  ?linkto.
     ?origin  dbo:wikiPageID 9186.
    }
''')
sparql.setReturnFormat(CSV)
qres = sparql.query().convert().decode('u8')
```

EDIT: I printed out the runtime of several hundreds queries (on local endpoint) and every single one of them took around 2.01 to 2.05 sec to complete, not even one is below 2 sec. So I thought somewhere along the pipeline there’s a fixed 2 sec delay, and the actual query only takes 10 to 50ms to complete.

Comment: It certainly doesn't sound like your "local SPARQL endpoint is very slow", but that your local ***Python*** (or SPARQLWrapper) is slow. Virtuoso doesn't much care what its client application is; we don't slow things for Python/SPARQLWrapper and speed them up for web browsers.

Comment: You might try changing `localhost` to `127.0.0.1`. DNS is often the cause of weirdly slow things like this.

Comment: Changing from `localhost` to `127.0.0.1` seems to do the trick for me, never thought of that. Thank you very much!

Comment: So neither Python nor Virtuoso is the cause here, just some weird DNS behavior.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I suggested in the comments, which did the trick --

> You might try changing `localhost` to `127.0.0.1`. DNS is often the cause of weirdly slow things like this.